# Why does one mongoDB compound index affect another compound index?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

From what I read from mongodb documents, only one index is used in a query. However, what I find is that the presence of some other compound indexes affect the quality of this query. Here is an example:

db.products.ensureIndex({'b' : 1, 'l.d' : 1, 'l.i' : 1})

db.products.find({'b' : {$in : b.ct}, 'l.d' : {$lt : d}}).limit(24).sort({'l.i' : 1}).explain()

```
{ "cursor" : "BtreeCursor b_1_l.d_1_l.i_1 multi",
"isMultiKey" : true,
"n" : 24,
"nscannedObjects" : 1079,
"nscanned" : 1102,
"nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 1182,
"nscannedAllPlans" : 1205,
"scanAndOrder" : true,
"indexOnly" : false,
"nYields" : 0,
"nChunkSkips" : 0,
....}
```

db.products.ensureIndex({'l.i' :1, 'b' : 1, 'l.d' : 1})

db.products.find({'b' : {$in : b.ct}, 'l.d' : {$lt : d}}).limit(24).sort({'l.i' : 1}).explain()

```
{ "cursor" : "BtreeCursor b_1_l.d_1_l.i_1 multi",
"isMultiKey" : true,
"n" : 24,
"nscannedObjects" : 614,
"nscanned" : 624,
"nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 1283,
"nscannedAllPlans" : 1875,
"scanAndOrder" : true,
"indexOnly" : false,
"nYields" : 1,
"nChunkSkips" : 0,
....}
```

The value of `nscanned` is reduced by almost half. Why?

================================================================

Based on the comments, I updated my command line sequence to provide more detailed information. Note the index names are changed because I modified the database. The result is the same. Two indices are better, but why?

db.products.stats()

```
{
"ns" : "mytest.products",
"count" : 209607,
"size" : 90155636,
"avgObjSize" : 430.11748653432375,
"storageSize" : 123936768,
"numExtents" : 11,
"nindexes" : 1,
"lastExtentSize" : 37625856,
"paddingFactor" : 1,
"systemFlags" : 0,
"userFlags" : 0,
"totalIndexSize" : 5927600,
"indexSizes" : {
    "_id_" : 5927600
},
"ok" : 1
}
```

b.ct

```
[
2020,
3564969011,
2021,
15762981,
271619011,
2023,
2024,
2027,
3825141,
505092,
2025,
2028,
10825721,
2080,
2026,
2085,
2029,
2030,
2032,
3564970011,
2081,
2082,
2083,
2084,
271621011,
2087
```

]

d

ISODate("2012-11-30T00:00:00Z")

db.products.ensureIndex({'b': 1, 'd': 1, 'i' : 1})

db.products.stats()

```
{
"ns" : "mytest.products",
"count" : 209607,
"size" : 90155636,
"avgObjSize" : 430.11748653432375,
"storageSize" : 123936768,
"numExtents" : 11,
"nindexes" : 2,
"lastExtentSize" : 37625856,
"paddingFactor" : 1,
"systemFlags" : 0,
"userFlags" : 0,
"totalIndexSize" : 22614816,
"indexSizes" : {
    "_id_" : 5927600,
    "b_1_d_1_i_1" : 16687216
},
"ok" : 1
}
```

db.products.find({'b' : {$in : b.ct}, 'd' : {$lt : d}}).limit(24).sort({'i' : 1}).explain()

```
{
"cursor" : "BtreeCursor b_1_d_1_i_1 multi",
"isMultiKey" : true,
"n" : 24,
"nscannedObjects" : 1294,
"nscanned" : 1300,
"nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 1395,
"nscannedAllPlans" : 1401,
"scanAndOrder" : true,
"indexOnly" : false,
"nYields" : 0,
"nChunkSkips" : 0,
"millis" : 12,
"indexBounds" : {
    "b" : [
        [
            2020,
            2020
        ],
        [
            2021,
            2021
        ],
        [
            2023,
            2023
        ],
        [
            2024,
            2024
        ],
        [
            2025,
            2025
        ],
        [
            2026,
            2026
        ],
        [
            2027,
            2027
        ],
        [
            2028,
            2028
        ],
        [
            2029,
            2029
        ],
        [
            2030,
            2030
        ],
        [
            2032,
            2032
        ],
        [
            2080,
            2080
        ],
        [
            2081,
            2081
        ],
        [
            2082,
            2082
        ],
        [
            2083,
            2083
        ],
        [
            2084,
            2084
        ],
        [
            2085,
            2085
        ],
        [
            2087,
            2087
        ],
        [
            505092,
            505092
        ],
        [
            3825141,
            3825141
        ],
        [
            10825721,
            10825721
        ],
        [
            15762981,
            15762981
        ],
        [
            271619011,
            271619011
        ],
        [
            271621011,
            271621011
        ],
        [
            3564969011,
            3564969011
        ],
        [
            3564970011,
            3564970011
        ]
    ],
    "d" : [
        [
            true,
            ISODate("2012-11-30T00:00:00Z")
        ]
    ],
    "i" : [
        [
            {
                "$minElement" : 1
            },
            {
                "$maxElement" : 1
            }
        ]
    ]
},
"server" : "li91-182:27017"
}
```

db.products.ensureIndex({'i': 1, 'b': 1, 'd' : 1})

db.products.stats()

```
{
"ns" : "mytest.products",
"count" : 209607,
"size" : 90155636,
"avgObjSize" : 430.11748653432375,
"storageSize" : 123936768,
"numExtents" : 11,
"nindexes" : 3,
"lastExtentSize" : 37625856,
"paddingFactor" : 1,
"systemFlags" : 0,
"userFlags" : 0,
"totalIndexSize" : 39302032,
"indexSizes" : {
    "_id_" : 5927600,
    "b_1_d_1_i_1" : 16687216,
    "i_1_b_1_d_1" : 16687216
},
"ok" : 1
}
```

db.products.find({'b' : {$in : b.ct}, 'd' : {$lt : d}}).limit(24).sort({'i' : 1}).explain()

```
{
"cursor" : "BtreeCursor b_1_d_1_i_1 multi",
"isMultiKey" : true,
"n" : 24,
"nscannedObjects" : 206,
"nscanned" : 206,
"nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 445,
"nscannedAllPlans" : 619,
"scanAndOrder" : true,
"indexOnly" : false,
"nYields" : 0,
"nChunkSkips" : 0,
"millis" : 6,
"indexBounds" : {
    "b" : [
        [
            2020,
            2020
        ],
        [
            2021,
            2021
        ],
        [
            2023,
            2023
        ],
        [
            2024,
            2024
        ],
        [
            2025,
            2025
        ],
        [
            2026,
            2026
        ],
        [
            2027,
            2027
        ],
        [
            2028,
            2028
        ],
        [
            2029,
            2029
        ],
        [
            2030,
            2030
        ],
        [
            2032,
            2032
        ],
        [
            2080,
            2080
        ],
        [
            2081,
            2081
        ],
        [
            2082,
            2082
        ],
        [
            2083,
            2083
        ],
        [
            2084,
            2084
        ],
        [
            2085,
            2085
        ],
        [
            2087,
            2087
        ],
        [
            505092,
            505092
        ],
        [
            3825141,
            3825141
        ],
        [
            10825721,
            10825721
        ],
        [
            15762981,
            15762981
        ],
        [
            271619011,
            271619011
        ],
        [
            271621011,
            271621011
        ],
        [
            3564969011,
            3564969011
        ],
        [
            3564970011,
            3564970011
        ]
    ],
    "d" : [
        [
            true,
            ISODate("2012-11-30T00:00:00Z")
        ]
    ],
    "i" : [
        [
            {
                "$minElement" : 1
            },
            {
                "$maxElement" : 1
            }
        ]
    ]
},
"server" : "li91-182:27017"
}
```

db.products.getIndexes()

```
[
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "_id" : 1
    },
    "ns" : "mytest.products",
    "name" : "_id_"
},
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "b" : 1,
        "d" : 1,
        "i" : 1
    },
    "ns" : "mytest.products",
    "name" : "b_1_d_1_i_1"
},
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "i" : 1,
        "b" : 1,
        "d" : 1
    },
    "ns" : "mytest.products",
    "name" : "i_1_b_1_d_1"
}
]
```

db.products.dropIndex({'i': 1, 'b': 1, 'd' : 1})
    { "nIndexesWas" : 3, "ok" : 1 }

db.products.getIndexes()

```
[
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "_id" : 1
    },
    "ns" : "mytest.products",
    "name" : "_id_"
},
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "b" : 1,
        "d" : 1,
        "i" : 1
    },
    "ns" : "mytest.products",
    "name" : "b_1_d_1_i_1"
}
]
```

db.products.find({'b' : {$in : b.ct}, 'd' : {$lt : d}}).limit(24).sort({'i' : 1}).explain()

```
{
"cursor" : "BtreeCursor b_1_d_1_i_1 multi",
"isMultiKey" : true,
"n" : 24,
"nscannedObjects" : 1294,
"nscanned" : 1300,
"nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 1395,
"nscannedAllPlans" : 1401,
"scanAndOrder" : true,
"indexOnly" : false,
"nYields" : 0,
"nChunkSkips" : 0,
"millis" : 131,
"indexBounds" : {
    "b" : [
        [
            2020,
            2020
        ],
        [
            2021,
            2021
        ],
        [
            2023,
            2023
        ],
        [
            2024,
            2024
        ],
        [
            2025,
            2025
        ],
        [
            2026,
            2026
        ],
        [
            2027,
            2027
        ],
        [
            2028,
            2028
        ],
        [
            2029,
            2029
        ],
        [
            2030,
            2030
        ],
        [
            2032,
            2032
        ],
        [
            2080,
            2080
        ],
        [
            2081,
            2081
        ],
        [
            2082,
            2082
        ],
        [
            2083,
            2083
        ],
        [
            2084,
            2084
        ],
        [
            2085,
            2085
        ],
        [
            2087,
            2087
        ],
        [
            505092,
            505092
        ],
        [
            3825141,
            3825141
        ],
        [
            10825721,
            10825721
        ],
        [
            15762981,
            15762981
        ],
        [
            271619011,
            271619011
        ],
        [
            271621011,
            271621011
        ],
        [
            3564969011,
            3564969011
        ],
        [
            3564970011,
            3564970011
        ]
    ],
    "d" : [
        [
            true,
            ISODate("2012-11-30T00:00:00Z")
        ]
    ],
    "i" : [
        [
            {
                "$minElement" : 1
            },
            {
                "$maxElement" : 1
            }
        ]
    ]
},
"server" : "li91-182:27017"
}
```

Comment: Did you insert or update any data between the find/ensureIndex/find?  What version of MongoDB is this?

Comment: can you share other indexes that may be present as well?

Comment: I only have that index, other than the _id.

Comment: I did not insert or update any data between those operations. The MongoDB I used is 2.2. The result is quite consistent. On some data, I see that the nscanned is dropped to only 10% when the second index is added (from ~3000 to ~300). I also tried to hint mongodb to use the second index to do the search, the nscanned value is similar to the second find above. That also confused me. Isn't it supposed to index the sort value last? The reason I don't always use the second index is because on some data it behaves much worse than the first one.

Comment: do you get this consistently ? I am unable to reproduce ? Can you provide your dataset ?

Comment: Could you provide us with the result of `db.products.getIndexes()` query? I doubt if there are two different indexes or a just single one.

Comment: I updated the question to provide more detailed information. The result is the same. Why?

Answer (score 3):

According to 10gen [BSON is a bin­ary-en­coded seri­al­iz­a­tion of JSON-like doc­u­ments](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/BSON). However the order of fields in BSON documents does matter:

```
> db.things.insert({b:1,d:1,i:1});
> db.things.insert({i:2,b:2,d:2});
> db.things.insert({d:3,i:3,b:3});
> db.things.find();
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50904ee4875db529686c5775"), "b" : 1, "d" : 1, "i" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50904ef0875db529686c5776"), "i" : 2, "b" : 2, "d" : 2 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50904efc875db529686c5777"), "d" : 3, "i" : 3, "b" : 3 }
```

So, whenever you're creating index with `db.products.ensureIndex({'b' : 1, 'l.d' : 1, 'l.i' : 1})` and then with `db.products.ensureIndex({'l.i' :1, 'b' : 1, 'l.d' : 1})` you got 2 indexes with **different** order of fields. This can be checked via result of `db.products.getIndexes()` you've kindly provided:

```
[{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "b" : 1,
        "d" : 1,
        "i" : 1
    },
    "ns" : "mytest.products",
    "name" : "b_1_d_1_i_1"
},
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "i" : 1,
        "b" : 1,
        "d" : 1
    },
    "ns" : "mytest.products",
    "name" : "i_1_b_1_d_1"
}]
```

And ifferent order of fields obviously may lead to different `nscanned` value - [the number of items (including index tree nodes) to be scanned](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Explain#Explain-nscanned):

> Number of items (documents or index entries) examined. Items might be
>   objects or index keys.

Comment: However, in both cases, the same index is used:
"cursor" : "BtreeCursor b_1_d_1_i_1 multi",

So, even the second index is added, it is not used in the query.